# How to prevent gravity from accelerating ground plane?

Tags: drake

I currently have a ground plane defined in `sdf` format with the following tags

- `<static>true</static>`
- `<gravity>false</gravity>`

In my source file, I specify

```
plant.AddForceElement<UniformGravityFieldElement>();
```

Question:

1. Is the `<static>` and `<gravity>` tags respected? Or does this `GravityFieldElement` affect everything?
2. If the tags are not respected, how do I prevent the `GravityFieldElement` from accelerating my ground plane?

Answer (score 1):

One way to add a ground plane is

```
Vector3<double> normal_W(0, 0, 1);
Vector3<double> point_W(0, 0, 0);

const CoulombFriction<double> surface_friction(
  0.8 /* static friction */, 0.3 /* dynamic friction */);

// A half-space for the ground geometry.
plant.RegisterCollisionGeometry(
    plant.world_body(), HalfSpace::MakePose(normal_W, point_W),
    HalfSpace(), "collision", surface_friction);

// Add visual for the ground.
plant.RegisterVisualGeometry(
    plant.world_body(), HalfSpace::MakePose(normal_W, point_W),
    HalfSpace(), "visual");
```

And after `plant.Finalize()`

```
plant.set_penetration_allowance(0.001);
```

Though I'd very much like to know if there's a way to do this through `sdf`